# jQuery: prevent click queue

Tags: jquery, event-propagation

```
$("#right").live("click", function(event) {
    $(".image_scroll").animate({"left": "+=300px"}, "slow");
});
```

I need the click to basically not register until the animation is done.
I've tried using `return false` but that just seems to kill the link entirely.

Tried also using `$(".image_scroll").stop().animate({"left": "+=300px"}, "slow");` but that just makes the animation stutter and look glitchy.

Edit: The id `#right` is on an image, not an `a` tag. The HTML is as follows:

```
<img src="/images/right.png" id="right" alt="" />
<div id="container">
    <div id="image_scroll">
        <img src="1.jpg" />
        <img src="3.jpg" />
        <img src="4.jpg" />
    </div><!-- /#image_scroll -->
</div> <!-- /#container
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a callback to animate...

```
$("#right").live("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var src = $(this).attr('href');
    $(".image_scroll").animate({"left": "+=300px"}, "slow", function() { window.location.href = src; });
});
```

Comment: what if it's not using an `a` link? The id #right is on an image

Comment: What does the click on the image do? If you raise the click event again on #right, how do you tell the difference between the initial click (which you just prevented so you could animate) and a click triggered after the animation. You can do it in a very hacky way using a global flag, but why not just execute the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to store the whether the animation is running or not, you could use the jQuery.data function for that:

```
$("#right").live("click", function(event) {
    var el = $(this),
        state = el.data('animation_state');
    if(state == 'busy') {
       //ignore clicks while the animation is running
       return false;
    } 
    el.data('animation_state', 'busy');
    $(".image_scroll").animate({"left": "+=300px"}, "slow", function() {
       //finished animating      
       //set the state to finished so we can click the element the next time
      el.data('animation_state', 'complete'); 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var handler = function(event) {
    $("#right").die("click");
    $(".image_scroll").animate({"left": "+=300px"}, "slow", function(){
        $("#right").live("click", handler);
    });
};
$("#right").live("click", handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the animation is running and, if so,

```
$("#right").live("click", function(event) {

    if ( $(".image_scroll").is(":animated") ) {
      return false;
    }

    $(".image_scroll").animate({"left": "+=300px"}, "slow");
});
```